# Java: Converting data types

Tags: java

I'm working with a `JTable`, whose cells data are contained in `Object`. One column shows a `float` number. I want to GET the value into a`float`, limit decimal places to 3, and then I want to reload the correct data in the cell, so I want to SET the value into the cell again. The problem appears in the last conversion:

```
 private class CambioTablaMeasurementListener implements TableModelListener{

    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e){
        try{
            if(sendDataToDisp){
                TableModel model = (TableModel)e.getSource();
                float value = Float.parseFloat((String)model.getValueAt(e.getLastRow(), 1));
               // Now i want to limit to only 3 decimal places, so:

                double aux = Math.round(value*1000.0)/1000.0;
                value = (float) aux;
                Float F = new Float(value);

                // Now i want to load data back to the cell, so if you enter 0.55555, the cell shows 0.555. This Line gives me an exception (java.lang.Float cannot be cast to java.lang.String):
                model.setValueAt(F, e.getLastRow(), 1);

                // Here I'm getting another column, no problem here:
                String nombreAtributo = (String)model.getValueAt(e.getLastRow(), 0);
                nodoAModificar.setCommonUserParameter(nombreAtributo, value);

            }
           ...}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DecimalFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) to display a float as a String in a given format:

```
...
float value = Float.parseFloat((String)model.getValueAt(e.getLastRow(), 1));             
DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
model.setValueAt(dec.format(value), e.getLastRow(), 1);
...
```

Comment: Still getting an exceptión. A really long one, Eclipse doesn't show which one it is because it's really long.

Comment: I have been able to check which exception it is: java.lang.StackOverflowError again

Comment: Possibly because the setValueAt triggers another tableChanged() event?

Comment: OK, I realised that changing the value is getting me into the Listener function again and again, but that's is a different problem I asked in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424144/java-stackoverflowerror

Thanks everybody, I'll close this question

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert `Float` instance to `String`.

```
model.setValueAt(F.toString(), e.getLastRow(), 1);
```

or

```
model.setValueAt(String.valueOf(F), e.getLastRow(), 1); // preferred since it performs null check
```

Comment: Gives me java.lang.StackOverflowError

Comment: @Roman Rdgz: so you have another problem.post your stacktrace.